# if statement in mysql query codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have to execute a query checking if a variable is empty or not. like:

```
if($symbol == ""){
    $data_array = $this->db->select('*')
                       ->select_max('date')
                    ->get('company')
                ->row_array();                  
}else{
    $data_array = $this->db->select('*')
                   ->select_max('date')
               ->where('symbol',$symbol)
               ->get('company')
               ->row_array();

    }
```

How can I make it in a single query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do it like this:

```
if($symbol == ""){
    $where  = "symbol != 0"; ##$where  = "symbol != ''"; whichever suits your case
}else{
    $where  = "symbol = '".$symbol."'";
}

$data_array = $this->db->select('*')
                    ->select_max('date')
                    ->where($where, false, false)
                    ->get('company')
                    ->row_array();
```